# usage of "barely"

Tags: word-usage

[From Young Sheldon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Sheldon) Season two, episode three. Sheldon's mother, Mary, says

> Stephanie Hanson's daughter was in a car accident last night. She
> died. Oh, no. My God. She was **barely** 16.

I guess "barely", "just" and "only" are interchangeable here and used to emphasize that girl was so young.

Is my understanding correct?

I can use this expression during the period of time that is after her 16-year-old birthday and before her 17-year-old birthday, right?

In other words, Suppose that girl was born at January 1, 2000. During the period of time that is after `January 1, 2016` and before `January 1, 2017`, I can say "She was barely 16".

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Barely* in this sense means *only just.* The girl would have been within a few weeks of her sixteenth birthday.

*Only sixteen* could be used if she was at any point in her seventeenth year.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give my example of `born at  January 1, 2000` a simple feedback?

Comment: If she was born _on_ (not _at_) Jan. 1, 2000, she would be considered as 'barely sixteen' for the first few weeks of 2016. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I guess I got it. Thank you. After the first few weeks of 2016, I should use "sixteen", rather than "barely sixteen", right?

Comment: Yes, or _only sixteen_ if you wanted to emphasise her youth.